# How do I correctly access my PHP files? Directly from JS or a thru a "master" PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, security

I'm not sure I fully understand this aspect of site security, but seems it is a bad idea to keep PHP files on root, so we move them into a PHP folder, and we call this folder phpIncludes. Some issues that are obscure are:

1) how do I access a file doStuff.php inside phpIncludes? From javascript? Seems to be a bad idea to have my javascript tell the name of the folder where sensitive stuff is, as in:

```
 executeAjaxCall("phpFiles/doStuff.php",success,error);
```

2) Or from a "master" PHP that resides on root? Can't that be tampered with for being on root?

```
$secretVariableThatOnlyThisPHPWouldKnow="bla"; //then check it in the included file? Does that work?
//in JS 
executeAjaxCall("masterFile.php?fileNeeded=doStuff");

//in PHP
$secretVar="bla";
include("myPathString/phpIncludes/".$_GET['fileNeeded'].".php");

//in all other INCLUDEable PHP files
if (!isset($secretVar))
{ 
    die();
}
if (!isFromThisDomain)
{
    die();
}
```

(How do I perform last test?)

What I have in mind is: "If someone wants to get the PHP files inside folder phpIncludes they can't, but they can access them thru HTML so requests need to be validated. Is it easily doable without sessions, like generating something in master.php that doStuff.php would recognize and hence do its job? Or is sessions the way to go?"
I am actually wondering about the "no session" scenario for this frees me from the task of attempting to implement anti-session hijacking code (if I ever learn it...). On the other hand, I am also thinking:"Isnt the variable secretVar accessable/tamperable since it will be on root?"

3) Do as (2), but have master.php inside yet ANOTHER folder (lets call it "master"), making it non-root? In this case, do I access my phpIncludes folder from the master folder using getcwd()+string manipulation? Or is there a "more elegant" (lazier...) method?

3 seems magical, where the only file I have on root would be index.php, that simply starts the HTML+JS and does nothing sensitive. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why not `if ( $_POST['section'] == "some_script" ) { require('phpIncludes/yourIncludeScript.php'); }`? Basically using the master PHP file to only `require()` other scripts and let them do their work? Basically work as a sort of "router".

Comment: I'm thinking: say someone sends me this: performAjax ("master.php?section=deleteUser&userToDelete=destroyerDataPerceivedAsValid") :D

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. So master.php would have something like `if ( $_GET['section'] == "deleteUser" ) { require('phpIncludes/delete.php'); }` and your phpIncludes/delete.php would have something like `$user_to_delete = $_GET['userToDelete']; /* sanitize input and delete user if valid */`

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't make something clear: the 'userToDelete' is NOT really valid... it is PERCEIVED as valid because it is a true ID, but it wasn't the legal user who sent it, but a malicious script that 'somehow' (I hear these things happen...) got someone's valid ID. I know there are other techniques to address that - that I will very soon ask here on SO :) - like dynamically creating an ID etc, but I'm paranoid and if Im getting as many layers of brute force defence as I can... (I'm actually worse than paranoid, I used to crack software as a hobby a long time ago... :D)

Comment: Hmmm... I would say you would then use a framework with that embedded. There are just too many things to consider, nothing is really completely secure, especially on web servers (which on their own have bugs too *(!)*). I personally like to use the XSS filter of CodeIgniter (which has a encription with a passphrase to encode the cookies on the client), but probably Zend Framework or even Symfony have better security for that.

Comment: But guess what? You, along with Mr. deceze, made my day! One bit of information that is a killer here (at least for me!) is that the "$_GET" ALSO passes thru. Isn't it duh once you see it? :D NOW I got the full impact of what you said :D. I'm about to "Um... how do I distribute the (lots of already written) data to different files?" when it hit me! *blush*

Comment: Read this, should be clarifying for you: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm (you have `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` separatedly... you also have `$_REQUEST` mixing them all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely irrelevant how your PHP file and folder structure is. The only thing that matters is this:

**What happens when you access a particular *URL*?**

`phpFiles/doStuff.php` is a *URL* first and foremost. It doesn't matter how you access it ("directly" via the browser address bar, via AJAX, curl, whatever else); all that matters is what happens *when* you access that URL. And it's entirely up to you to ensure that nothing undesirable will happen with each URL access.

1. Don't publicly expose any URLs which aren't meant to exist in the first place. If you have a bunch of .php files which aren't mean to be accessed directly via a URL, then don't publicly expose them. That either means that you block access to them via your web server configuration (e.g. `deny all` in an .htaccess file), or that you take those files out of the public webroot to begin with.
2. Validate all input and necessary conditions in all publicly exposed URL endpoints as necessary. The user needs to be logged in to do something? Verify that. You require certain query parameters or POST body data? Verify that. Validate and verify every incoming request on its own merits before doing anything. Whether you repeat this validation code in each file individually or do it somewhere centrally is up to you.
3. Split your code across multiple files as appropriate to make it reusable. See points 1. and 2., you must simply take care which files are publicly exposed as URL *entry points* and at which point you need to do what sort of validation.

Comment: Great! thanks for your interest :) Just one last point: by 'entry point' on 3 you mean A) php that is on root (entry point to domain), and not B) the starting lines of a php file right? (entry point of a program/script). And if it is  A, I understand that "entry point"  and "php on root" would be synonyms, right? (I've gone wrong with terminology before... one of the curses of the amateur :)

Comment: I simply mean whatever will kick off your code execution. You can see that from the perspective of the URL/HTTP request (that URL is one *entry point* into your application) or from your code perspective ("first line in file"). The important point is to recognise it as *entry point*; e.g. if you do certain validations in foo.php, but next to it is a bar.php which can be accessed directly and does something *without* that validation, then you've got one unprotected entry point. An image says more than a thousand words: https://twitter.com/old_sound/status/602996592531091456

Comment: Lol! you are the man! you meant LITERALLY an entry point, and ANY entry point :) Loud and clear :D Many thanks!

Comment: Another good point to mention (and that's why `$_GET` gets "passed thru") is that an `include()` call doesn't execute in a different process and gives you a result, it's read and evaluated in the first script. So if `a.php` includes `b.php` and then you ask for `a.php` on a browser, it will be `a.php` that runs everything (and it will behave like it has `b.php` content inside of it). It's `a.php` that's doing everything, it just read `b.php` and copied its behavior.